Is there a way to update Spectre.Console when a property changes?
I'm writing code for a device controller using COM connection. In my code i have 3 threads, listener, writer and state ask thread and for each of them i was planning to output their state (working or paused) and a timer for testing purposes using Spectre.Console LiveDisplay.
I can't figure out how to update the console when state property for each thread changes. Updating the console would require calling ctx.Refresh() every time state of every thread changes, but i didn't find a way to call it not from AnsiConsole.Start() method.
I'm using a separate class for storing states, to which i pass values from threads, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. I'm still not sure if implementing it in a separate class is a good way, so I'm planning to revisit this and maybe join it with controller class.
Here's my class for storing states:
internal class ControllerData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _writeThreadState = "";
        private string _readThreadState = "";
        private string _stateThreadState = "";
        private string _actionMessage = "";

        public String WriteThreadState
        {
            get => _writeThreadState;
            set
            {
                _writeThreadState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WriteThreadState));
            }
        }
        public String ReadThreadState
        {
            get => _readThreadState;
            set
            {
                _readThreadState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ReadThreadState));
            }
        }
        public String StateThreadState
        {
            get => _stateThreadState;
            set
            {
                _stateThreadState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StateThreadState));
            }
        }
        public String ActionMessage
        {
            get => _actionMessage;
            set
            {
                _actionMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ActionMessage));
            }
        }
        public StringBuilder Output { get; set; } = new StringBuilder();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

Logger class:
internal class Logger
    {
        private ControllerData data;

        public Logger(Controller cont)
        {
            data = cont.loggingData;
            data.PropertyChanged += ControllerDataPropertyChangedHandler;
        }

        private void ControllerDataPropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //refresh console
        }



        public void Start()
        {
            Table table = new Table()
                .Border(TableBorder.Rounded)
                .AddColumn("Thread")
                .AddColumn("State");

            table.AddRow("Listen Thread", data.ReadThreadState);
            table.AddRow("Write Thread", data.WriteThreadState);
            table.AddRow("Check state Thread", data.StateThreadState);


             AnsiConsole.Live(table)
                .Start(ctx =>
                {
                    ctx.Refresh();
                });

        }

    }

Main:
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ComConnector connector = new ComConnector();

            try
            {
                Controller cont = new Controller(connector);
                Logger log = new Logger(cont);
                log.Start();
                cont.StartMessaging(20000);
                
                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }

        }
    }


Can you extract a [mre] from that? Then we probably can provide a working poc.

BTW: I'd discourage to call a class "Logger". That term has a specific semantic in the C#/.NET eco system.

Mind that in your implementation, Logger.Start blocks and so the Main only can execute cont.StartMessaging after it returns. So you need some more concurrency, there.

This would need that you probably reconsider your design, but this is how I usually do it:
using Spectre.Console;
using SpectreTest;

Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;

var table = new Table().AddColumns("Key", "Value");

await AnsiConsole.Live(table).StartAsync(async ctx =>
{
    var sim = new CommunicationEmulator();
    var entries = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    await sim.SimulateAsync(new Progress<Update>(u =>
    {
        if (entries.TryGetValue(u.Key, out var rowIndex))
        {
            table.UpdateCell(rowIndex, 1, u.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            var columns = new List<Markup> { Markup.FromInterpolated($"{u.Key}"), 
                                             Markup.FromInterpolated($"{u.Value}") };
            var index = table.Rows.Add(columns);
            entries[u.Key] = index;
        }

        ctx.Refresh();
    }));
});

public record Update(string Key, string Value);

Give or take, this shows a Table, that will be Live-Updated by Reports from what I called CommunicationEmulator here.
You would probably be fine, too with using

Channel<T>
Reactive (which can adapt to event-based communication)

The point(s) being to loop inside the StartAsync and issue updates as you go and keep a mapping from some sort of key to the row-index of the actual table.
Mind that this is not accounting for user input. It just runs until there is no more input from the emulator.
